# Drools: timer vs. duration attributes

Tags: drools

Drools' [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/6.0.0.Final/drools-docs/html_single/index.html#d0e6607) says that *timer* attribute is preferred now over *duration*:

> Rules now support both interval and cron based timers, which replace the now deprecated duration attribute.

But I've detected that such rule wouldn't work:

```
rule "Expired auth"
    timer(int: 5s)

    when
        $auth   : Authorized()
        $noauth : NotAuthorized()
    then
        retract($auth);
        retract($noauth);
end
```

because when it gets evaluated a first time all the facts are being removed and the rule won't be scheduled as expected.
But I've found that a rule with *duration* attribute works as it should:

```
rule "Expired auth"
    duration(5s)

    ...
end
```

So is there any way to do it via *timer*s?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

duration is mapped to an interval timer, so they work the same. Your issue is probably else where.

See line 176 https://github.com/droolsjbpm/drools/blob/master/drools-compiler/src/main/java/org/drools/compiler/rule/builder/RuleBuilder.java#L176

Comment: Created some isolated tests and see no difference, you are right, eh. :)

Answer (score 1):

**file.drl**

```
rule "address should be in"
   timer(int: 5s 2s) //fire after 5s and will be continue every 2s untill the sleep time out.
   when
      $address: Address(postcode != null)
   then
    System.out.println(hello("rule is fired...."));
end
```

**java code**

```
// Active Mode
    KieSessionConfiguration config = KieServices.Factory.get().newKieSessionConfiguration();
    config.setOption( ClockTypeOption.get("realtime") );
    final KieSession session = kbase.newKieSession( config, null );

    session.setGlobal( "myGlobalList", list);
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            session.fireUntilHalt();
        }
    }).start();

    session.insert(address);
    Thread.sleep(30000L);
    System.out.println("end："+ list);
    session.halt();
    session.dispose();
```

Comment: Your answer is only code. Please add some explanation as well?

Comment: @A.shun this post is about `timer` vs `duration` and those are the same. The problem was in my logic.